# String Not Being Modified By strings.xml

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm using android sdk and am trying to change the name of a string. I've started a new project, the activity_main.xml shows Hello World! on the screen.

I go into strings.xml file and there was nothing even referencing this string so I added in

```
<string name="hello_world">Hello World!</string>
```

I tried modifying `Hello World!` and changed it to something like this:

```
<string name="hello_world">Helloooo Worldsss!</string>
```

yet nothing changed.

So I looked further into the textview of the activity_main.xml

and modified the `Textview` attribute `text` to:

```
android:text=@string/hello_world
```

now the text Hello World! has disappeared from the screen entirely. Perhaps it needs to be referenced to enter the strings.xml file from the textview of activity_main.xml?

I'm brand new to Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like simply a case of syntax; you need quote marks.

So `android:text="@string/hello_world"`

edit: to elaborate regarding the request below.

`android:text="Hello World"` would be perfectly valid code and would directly show the text 'Hello World' but it is bad practice to hard-code text like that.

When you use `android:text="@string/hello_world"` you are instructing the system to look for a string resource matching the name `hello_world` and insert whatever string you've specified there. Partly this helps with organisation of your app text, but the main advantage is for localisation. You could have different strings.xml files for English, French and Spanish for example, all with their own version of "Hello World" using the same name `hello_world`. The system would insert the appropriate string depending on the language of the users device.(obviously that's a whole different topic!)

You need the @string bit so that the system knows to look for a string resource, if you used `android:text="hello_world"`, that's valid and would just display the text "hello_world" (including the underscore).

Comment: Lewis McGeary, Thanks! I actually suspected that I needed quote marks but I put them around hello_world only, like this, `android:text=@string/"hello_world"` which obviously didn't work. Could you elaborate a bit on why I needed to include `@string/` as well?

Comment: I edited the answer to talk a bit about `@string`, hope it helps.